# Apache Virtual Host different depending on client ip?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

What I'm trying to accomplish is:

```
1. A person, with IP 192.168.1.5 loads my webserver (192.168.1.2) and reaches htdocs/
2. Another person, with ip 192.168.1.6 does the same request, and reaches htdocs/folder/
```

If possible, I'd like to stick to port 80 requests only.

I'm currently using the setup:

```
<LocationMatch "/">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 localhost 192.168.1.5
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>  

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.2:80>
    ServerAdmin frederik@*.dk
    DocumentRoot "/XAMPP/htdocs/"
    ServerName 192.168.1.2
    ErrorLog "logs/lan-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/lan-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I'd like to allow everyone else to see the folder. And then, depending on the client IP, set another DocumentRoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it the way you're envisioning (with conditional `DocumentRoot`). However, you can achieve the same thing with Apache Rewrites by adding the following to your `VirutalHost` declaration, or in the `.htaccess` file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^192\.168\.1\.5
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /blog [R=301,L]
```

Essentially, if the user's IP isn't your IP address, and they're not requesting something in the `/blog` folder, it will redirect them to the `/blog` folder. If it's your IP address, or if they're requesting something in the `/blog` folder, then no redirect will occur.

Comment: I believe I'll stick to listening to another port. But upvoted and accepted, for a legit answer.